# Que me falla en este código?

Tags: python, string, split

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que consiste en crear mi propia función que funcione como el método split. Al pasarle como argumento una cadena que termine en un caracter es donde me falla y no me añade la última palabra a la lista. De ahí que haya añadido la condición x==len(cadena), condición que yo creo que sí debería cumplirse y entrar en el elif al leer la última letra de la cadena.
Es un ejercicio sencillo pero no consigo entender por que no se cumple esa condición.

```
def misplit(cadena):
  lista=[]
  palabra=""
  x=0
  try:
    if type(cadena)!=str:
        raise TypeError
    
    for i in cadena:
        x+=1
        if i.isalnum()==True:
            palabra+=i
            
        elif i.isalnum()==False or x==len(cadena):
            lista.append(palabra)
            palabra=""
    
    return lista


  except TypeError:
    print("El argumento no es una cadena.")


print(misplit("Esto es una prueba"))
```

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿que es lo que debe hacer tu ejercicio?, especifica por favor, revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes mejorar un par de cosas.

1.- No necesitas gestionar la longitud de la cadena

2.- Ampliar para que puedas utilizar diferentes separadores, no solo el espacio

```
def mi_split(cadena, separador =' '):
    lista = []
    palabra = ""
    try:
        if type(cadena) != str:
            raise TypeError

        for caracter in cadena:            #    Lee la cadena
            if caracter != separador:
                palabra += caracter
            else:                           #   Cuando encuentra un separador
                lista.append(palabra)           #   Añade a la lista
                palabra = ''                    #   Inicializa
        lista.append(palabra)           #   Añade a la lista la parte que falta
        return lista

    except TypeError:
        print("El argumento no es una cadena.")


print(mi_split("Esto/es una/prueba", '/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta en que al finalizar la cadena, el ultimo caracter es alfanumerico por lo cual lo añade a la palabra que estas formando, pero entonces se termina la cadena y esa palabra se queda en el aire (??). hay dos soluciones. 1 al entrar a tu funcion le agregas al final un espacio en blanco a la cadena. 2 agregas una linea de codigo con un if que chequee si hay algo en la palabra despues que termina el for.
aqui te dejo la segunda solución.

```
## Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que consiste en crear mi propia función que funcione
## como el método split. Al pasarle como argumento una cadena que termine en un
## caracter es donde me falla y no me añade la última palabra a la lista.
## De ahí que haya añadido la condición x==len(cadena), condición que yo creo que
## sí debería cumplirse y entrar en el elif al leer la última letra de la cadena.
## Es un ejercicio sencillo pero no consigo entender por que no se cumple esa condición.

def misplit(cadena):
  lista=[]
  palabra=""
  x=0
  try:
    if type(cadena)!=str:
        raise TypeError
    for i in cadena:
        x+=1
        if i.isalnum()==True:
            palabra+=i
        elif i.isalnum()==False or x==len(cadena):
            lista.append(palabra)
            palabra=""
    if len(palabra) > 0: lista.append(palabra)
    return lista
  except TypeError:
    print("El argumento no es una cadena.")

print(misplit("Esto es una prueba"))
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ahora lo veo. 
Sabía que era fácil pero no pensé que tanto, no se como no he caído, a ver si me voy haciendo poco a poco al codigo.